# Waning: Undefined array key when trying to store post variables (xmlhttprequest)

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to save the data that "buchen.php" get in php variables but I keep getting the following error

**Warning:** Undefined array key "reise_id" in buchen.php on line 4

**Warning:** Undefined array key "platz_geb" in buchen.php on line 5

Can anyone tell what could be wrong here?

```
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'buchen.php');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
        reise_id: "<?php echo $reise_id; ?>",
        platz_geb: platz_blau
    }));
```

```
//buchen.php

    $reise_id = $_POST['reise_id'];
    $platz_geb = $_POST['platz_geb'];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of grabbing the POST variables as always, try the following on the PHP code:

```php
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
echo $json;
```

Comment: But why would this be necessary?

Comment: I don't do PHP anymore, but as far as I could remember, file_get_contents() converts a file  to a string, and you are passing php://input, which is basically the request body. So you are converting the JSON Object to string so you can work with it.